# Prove that this equality is not achieved : $21+a^{2}+a^{bc}≠ a^{c+1}+a^{c+1}+(bc)^{a}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

I need prove for all $a$ natural number such $a\geq 2$ and for all $b,c$ tow prime numbers then :

$$21+a^{2}+a^{bc}≠ a^{c+1}+a^{b+1}+(bc)^{a}$$

**My attempts**

I studied two cases :

**1** • for $a\geq bc$ Then minimum values of $a$ is $4$ then For this reason, equality is incorrect So this situation is not possible.

**2** • for $a\leq bc$

I don't know to complete

---

I need some hints and thanks to all!

Comment: If $e < x < y$ than $x^y > y^x$

Comment: But how I use it ? To complete !

Comment: Please include an actual attempt to solve the problem.